# NodeJS: changing current directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a directory structure like below

```
MainApp
 --register.html
 routes
    --aws.js
```

From `aws.js`, I want to go one level up and render the file register.html.I have below in `aws.js`

```
var process = require('process');
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    const { fname, lname, email, phone, zip } = req.body;
    process.chdir("../");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/register.html'));
});
```

But this doesn't work. It still searches for `register.html` in the current directory (`routes`) where clearly there is no `register.html`

What am I missing?

Comment: Use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory) instead of [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)

Comment: @alfasin tried that, it takes me to the desktop (2 level up)

Comment: Why bother with the current directory at all since it isn't used in your `res.sendFile()` anyway?  Why not just use `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../register.html'));`  If you're changing the current directory in order to affect some other request that comes later, that is likely a very bad design since you can have multiple users using the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 tried that before posting, doesn't work

Comment: > ***But this doesn't work. It still searches for register.html in the current directory (routes) where clearly there is no register.html*** - Well, that's because you're sending an absolute path to `res.sendFile()` which does not use the current working directory in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it. Had to remove `process.chdir("../");` and add `process.cwd()`

The working code

```
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    const { fname, lname, email, phone, zip } = req.body;
    //process.chdir("../");
    res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd() + '/register.html'));
});
```

Comment: If you're going to use `path.join()` at all, then it should be: `res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), '/register.html'))`.  Otherwise, just do `res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/register.html');`.  `path.join()` is useful only when you pass it multiple arguments.